# How to search rows in order to check if the row contains a value and only extract that specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through rows of a dataframe to search whether a value is TRUE. The dataframe looks like:

```
Mass    900.5    901.5    902.5    1000.5    1001.5   
Height  100      200      300      400       500
mass
901.4  FALSE     TRUE     FALSE    FALSE     FALSE
903.5  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     FALSE
1001.4 FALSE     FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

As you can see, a row may have 'TRUE' or may only have 'FALSE'. I want to iterate over rows for the 1st column after mass, and search if a row does not have 'TRUE'. If a row doesn't have 'TRUE', then I want to assign the value for that specific row as empty space (equivalent to None in python I believe). My current code pulls the 'TRUE' values and collects the corresponding Height values.

For example, the above dataframe after using my code will yield:

current results:

```
Mass    Height
901.4   200
1001.4  500
```

code 1:

```
matches = pd.DataFrame(index=pickuplist['mass'],
                        columns=df.set_index(list(df.columns)).index,
                        dtype=bool)
```

Just FYI, code 1 is where matches df is initially defined.

code 2:

```
for index, exp_mass, intensity in df.itertuples():
    matches[exp_mass] = abs(matches.index - exp_mass)/matches.index < ppm/1e6
```

The above line is what creates the example dataframe after picking up values based on ppm tolerance.

code 3:

```
list = matches.any().reset_index(name='a')[matches.any().values]
```

The above line is what I believe extracts mass and Height values (current results table).

I tried using if/iloc and others to see if I could assign None to the specific row, but did not work. The expected results should be:

list:

```
Mass    Height
901.4   200
903.5   
1001.4  500
```

---

(Edit1)
I tried using the first answer's suggestions, and it gave me like:

```
    Height
0   TRUE
1   TRUE
2   TRUE
```

Maybe the dataframes' formats are different. No False or NaN values as well. Please note that there is an empty line between Height row and 901.4 row.

(Edit2)
Tried using the suggestions from the second answer, and it gave me:

```
    Mass    Height
0   901.4   (901.4, 200)
1   903.5   (903.5, 518)
2   1001.4  (1001.4, 500)
```

The index 1 row's height value is supposed to be empty but got a random value for some reason. By looking at the imported data that goes into the matches dataframe, the 518 value seems to be the first Height value of the data.

The original data that get feed into matches dataframe looks like:

```
Mass    Height
899.1   518
900.5   100
901.5   200
902.5   300
950.5   400
1000.5  400
1001.5  500
```

and so forth.

Comment: What happen if multiple `True`s  per rows?

Comment: There shouldn't be multiple Trues per row as each row can have either none or one mass pickup value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want first `True` value if exist, else `NaN` first remove first level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), then add new column with name `NaN` for match rows with `False` only and last use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for column of first `True` per rows:

```
df1 = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
df1[np.nan] = True
df2 = df1.idxmax(axis=1).rename_axis('Mass').reset_index(name='Height')
print (df2)
     Mass Height
0   901.4    200
1   903.5    NaN
2  1001.4    500
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions. Please see Edit2 of my post for an update.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - It seems like use only `df1.idxmax(axis=1)`, then get tuples in output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, it's not a really clean way but it will works for you.

I create a df like your result:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(index = [901.4, 903.5, 1001.4],
                      columns=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                      data=[[False, True, False, False, False],
                            [False, False, False, False, False],
                            [False, False, False, False, True]])
   df.index.name = 'mass'
   df.columns.name = 'Height'
```

Here I will pass for all the rows and create a new df with your correct format:

```
    import numpy as np

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Height'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if not row.any():
            new_df.loc[index, 'Height'] = np.nan
        else:
            new_df.loc[index, 'Height'] = row.any()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I tried your suggestions. Please see Edit1 of my post for an update. Thanks!